# Firebase file download on Android shows 0 bytes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I tried to download a file through FireBase to my app. I put logs in success/fail listeners, but those don't get processed, so I don't know if the download is happening at all. However, temp file shows 0 bytes in a log posted after the download method, so it looks like it's not working. How can I fix this?

Here is the code:

```
String nameOfFile = "name";
final File temp = File.createTempFile(nameOfFile,".db");

FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
StorageReference doc = storageRef.child("New Releases/" + fileName);

doc.getFile(temp).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Toast.makeText(BrowseTitles.this, "OnSuccess has run!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Note: Firebase files on the Firebase storage website show proper size of file, and Firebase permissions for this bucket allow reading/writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Nevermind, I figured it out. I didn't supply enough code. I had both a copy file and create database function happen outside of the OnSuccess listener within the method that posted the OnSuccess listener. Those extra functions acted on the temp file. One of these must've disrupted the download process. I put them inside of the OnSuccess listener and it worked perfectly.